# Python: json.load() error, every time

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, io

I generate a large nested dictionary and then save it as a json, then later on I try to load it (so that I can append more data to the json). However I am constantly getting an error on the following line of code:

```
 # to save
 with open(json_path,'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=3, sort_keys=True)

 # to load
 with open(json_path,'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Errors I have seen so far:
ValueError: end is out of bounds
ValueError: expecting object ...
ValueError: unterminated string ...

But the strange thing is: if I pdb after the exception and try to load the json again, it works everytime!

Comment: Are there multiple processes involved? Have you experienced any problems with your disk? You appear to experience incomplete reads (or the write didn't complete).

Comment: @FrEaKmAn: that'd be surprising, seeing as `json.dump()` is producing the JSON. The JSON appears to be *incomplete*.

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: Thanks Martijin, I realised that I was using threads and so the file hadn't finished writing before another thread tried to open it.

Comment: Then use a lock to coordinate reads and writes. You are reading too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading too early, and the write hasn't completed yet. If you are using separate processes or threads, you'll need to make sure you serialise read and write operations.

Use a lock to make sure the write operation completes before you attempt to read.